# Flutter: in app update without google/apple store?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, apk

My company (where I work) created an application for a company. I worked alone on this app and nobody else is into mobile developing + I am new in application developing. I use the firebase app distribution function to share the APK with the testers.

The problem that the testers are bored that they always get an email when there is a new version and have to install the new version through that.

Is it possbile to achieve some kind of in-app-update without using google/apple store? This app is for a company, that is not an option to put it on google/apple store.

The packages I found are using the store...

https://pub.dev/packages/new_version

https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_update

Sorry for the newbie question, thanks you in advance.

Comment: I know its late, but did you find any solution or workaround for this?

Comment: Nope. And I am not working there anymore so I don't know if they found a way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following steps:

- Enable Firebase Storage
- Name your apks by version code
- When you run your app, search the Firebase Storage for the max version code file
- Compare running app's version with max
- Download
- Launch installer

Note: This is not in-app-update, but rather an automated process for downloading updates to a device. And launching installs may be restricted on Android 11 and higher, so look into that if necessary.